# how to change the color of the labels based on the colors of my plotted values?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have this df:

```
           DATE   TMAX       QUANTILE_TMAX_90   QUANTILE_TMAX_95   QUANTILE_TMAX_99
50415 2019-01-01  19.2               19.5               20.2               21.8
50416 2019-01-02  17.4               19.5               20.2               21.8
50417 2019-01-03  17.2               19.5               20.2               21.8
50418 2019-01-04  16.4               19.5               20.2               21.8
50419 2019-01-05  17.4               19.5               20.2               21.8
         ...   ...                ...                ...                ...
50500 2019-03-27  16.2               19.0               19.8               21.4
50501 2019-03-28  13.6               19.0               19.8               21.4
50502 2019-03-29  15.2               19.0               19.8               21.4
50503 2019-03-30  16.2               19.0               19.8               21.4
50504 2019-03-31  18.8               19.0               19.8               21.4

[90 rows x 5 columns]
```

I'm plotting colored dots and lines in the time series graphic of the values that meet a specific condition. yellow color if TMAX > QUANTILE_TMAX_90, orange color if TMAX > QUANTILE_TMAX_95, red color if TMAX > QUANTILE_TMAX_99.

This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

   colors = []
   axis_colors = []

   for tmax, p90, p95, p99 in zip(datos['TMAX'], datos['QUANTILE_TMAX_90'], datos['QUANTILE_TMAX_95'], datos['QUANTILE_TMAX_99']):
       if tmax > p99:
           colors.append('red')
       elif tmax > p95:
           colors.append('orange')
       elif tmax > p90:
           colors.append('yellow')
       else:
           colors.append('black')
   
   fig = plt.figure('Gráfica', figsize=(20,15), dpi=150)
   
   ax = fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.25, 0.60, 0.60])

   for date, tmax, color in zip(datos['DATE'], datos['TMAX'], colors):
       if color != 'black':
           ax.plot(date, tmax, color=color, marker='o')
   
   for i in range(len(datos)-1):
       ax.plot(datos['DATE'].iloc[i:i+2], datos['TMAX'].iloc[i:i+2], color=colors[i], linewidth=1)
```

And with this code:

```
   [t.set_color(color) for t, color in zip(ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels(), axis_colors) if color != 'black']
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

I want to change the color of the ticks based on the colors of my plotted values but is not working.

How can i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You are quite close to the answer. You are getting the ticklables and colors (should be colors, not axis_colors as you are not setting them anywhere), but are not setting the color (ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels()).
There are a couple of other changes that are required including setting the format for the date and requiring `plt.draw()` which is required before you can read the ticklables. Updated code below. Hope this is what you are looking for...

**Data**

```
>>> datos
ID  DATE    TMAX    QUANTILE_TMAX_90    QUANTILE_TMAX_95    QUANTILE_TMAX_99
0   50415   2019-01-01  22  19.5    20.2    21.8
1   50416   2019-01-02  21  19.5    20.2    21.8
2   50417   2019-01-03  20  19.5    20.2    21.8
3   50418   2019-01-04  19  19.5    20.2    21.8
4   50419   2019-01-05  18  19.5    20.2    21.8
5   50500   2019-01-06  22  19.0    19.8    21.4
6   50501   2019-01-07  21  19.0    19.8    21.4
7   50502   2019-01-08  20  19.0    19.8    21.4
8   50503   2019-01-09  19  19.0    19.8    21.4
9   50504   2019-01-10  18  19.0    19.8    21.4
```

**Updated code**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

colors = []
axis_colors = []
datos=pd.read_excel('input.xlsx', 'Sheet68')
for tmax, p90, p95, p99 in zip(datos['TMAX'], datos['QUANTILE_TMAX_90'], datos['QUANTILE_TMAX_95'], datos['QUANTILE_TMAX_99']):
   if tmax > p99:
       colors.append('red')
   elif tmax > p95:
       colors.append('orange')
   elif tmax > p90:
       colors.append('yellow')
   else:
       colors.append('black')

fig = plt.figure('Gráfica', figsize=(20,15), dpi=150)

ax = fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.25, 0.60, 0.60])

for date, tmax, color in zip(datos['DATE'], datos['TMAX'], colors):
   if color != 'black':
       ax.plot(date, tmax, color=color, marker='o')

for i in range(len(datos)-1):
   ax.plot(datos['DATE'].iloc[i:i+2], datos['TMAX'].iloc[i:i+2], color=colors[i], linewidth=1)

##New code - show in DD-MM-YYYY format and for each day 
myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=1))
plt.xticks(rotation=90)

plt.draw()  ## Needed so that you can read the plotted ticklables, else will be blanks

## Note that you need to use color, do NOT need to unselect black and use set_ticklables()
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels([t.set_color(color) for t, color in zip(ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels(), colors)])
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but i don't know why doesn't work. The code seems very well.

Comment: What do you mean by `why doesn't work`? What is the error you are getting?